# How to Mark a case as a 're-open' if the same Case Id occurred prior to the one being looked at

Tags: group-by, sql-server-2014

I have been trying a few various methods to see if I can get this to work, but I haven't had any luck.

Here is what I am trying to accomplish.

Every day, there are cases that get closed. We are wanting to track cases that have been 're-opened' after having been already closed once, but there is nothing in the information provided that tells us this is a re-opened case. The only way to do this is to check to see if the Case ID and the Report Date and see if the there is a duplicate Case Id that exists and was closed prior to this report date. To complicate matters, here is some additional info:

1) A common situation is that a case is closed, re-opened and then closed again within the same day(sometimes multiple times). This should count as a re-open, each time it is done after the first instance, even if it's the same day ( I assume we would group by case ID?)

2) I run a 5 Day reporting window, so a case should NOT count as a re-open if for instance on 3/20/2019 the case was closed for the first time, and then re-opened at some point and closed again 3/26/2019 until 3/26/2019. On 3/20, 3/21, 3/22, and 3/25(report days skips weekends and holidays, this is already built in, do not need anything fo that) it should NOT be marked as a re-open because the case still only has one instance on or before the report date we are looking at. On 3/26 it would be marked as a re-open because it would then have been closed for a second time on or before the report date.

Here are some queries:

```
CREATE TABLE ResolvedCases(
    Case_ID varchar(20),
    Case_Closed_On datetime,
    Report_Date date,
    Is_ReOpened_Case VarChar(3) NULL
) 

INSERT INTO ResolvedCases VALUES('US1236', '2019-02-16 12:30:45', '2/16/2019')
INSERT INTO ResolvedCases VALUES('US1238', '2019-02-28 15:30:45', '2/28/2019')
INSERT INTO ResolvedCases VALUES('US1234', '2019-03-19 12:30:45', '3/19/2019')
INSERT INTO ResolvedCases VALUES('US1234', '2019-03-19 15:30:45', '3/19/2019')
INSERT INTO ResolvedCases VALUES('US1235', '2019-03-20 9:30:45', '3/20/2019')
INSERT INTO ResolvedCases VALUES('US1235', '2019-03-23 12:40:45', '3/23/2019')
INSERT INTO ResolvedCases VALUES('US1236', '2019-03-20 12:30:45', '3/24/2019')
INSERT INTO ResolvedCases VALUES('US1237', '2019-03-25 12:30:45', '3/25/2019')
```

Expected Results(Only showing the cases with Report_Date between 3/20 and 3/26):

```
Case_ID    Case_Closed_On       Report_Date    Is_ReOpened_Case
US1234     2019-03-19 12:30:45    3/19/2019            No  (There is a duplicate case Id on 3/19 but it didn't happen until 3:30 PM---at 12:30PM this hadn't occurred yet so it was not a re-open at that time)
US1234     2019-03-19 15:30:45    3/19/2019            Yes
US1235     2019-03-20 9:30:45      3/20/2019            No (There is a duplicate case Id on 3/23 but on 3/20 this hadn't occurred yet so it was no a re-open on that date)
US1235     2019-03-23 12:40:45    3/23/2019            Yes
US1236     2019-03-20 12:30:45    3/24/2019            Yes (Because of the case closed on 2/16/2019 even though it doesn't show in this query)
US1237    2019-03-25 12:30:45     3/25/2019            No
```

Any help would be appreciated with this...

I have something that shows the count of the case ID which shows me all the duplicates for a given date range and have them grouped by Case_ID but I am not sure how to just mark each individual row as a re-open or not based on the requirements above...

Answer (score 0):

For your immediate problem, you can use [`LAG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to update your table with the flag you're looking for. (It returns a `NULL` if there's no preceding value, hence the logic in the `CASE` statement.)

```
UPDATE rc
  SET rc.Is_ReOpened_Case = sq.Is_ReOpened_Case
FROM 
  @ResolvedCases AS rc
  LEFT JOIN 
  (
    SELECT 
      Case_ID
     ,Case_Closed_On
     ,Report_Date
     ,Is_ReOpened_Case = 
        CASE 
          WHEN LAG(Case_ID) OVER (PARTITION BY Case_ID ORDER BY Case_Closed_On) IS NOT NULL 
           THEN 'Yes' 
          ELSE 'No' 
        END 
    FROM @ResolvedCases
  ) AS sq
    ON sq.Case_ID = rc.Case_ID
    AND sq.Case_Closed_On = rc.Case_Closed_On
WHERE
  COALESCE(rc.Is_ReOpened_Case,'') <> COALESCE(sq.Is_ReOpened_Case,'')


SELECT 
   rc.*
FROM @ResolvedCases AS rc
WHERE rc.Report_Date >= '20190319' AND rc.Report_Date < '20190326'
ORDER BY Case_ID, Case_Closed_On;
```

Results:

```
+---------+-------------------------+-------------+------------------+
| Case_ID |     Case_Closed_On      | Report_Date | Is_ReOpened_Case |
+---------+-------------------------+-------------+------------------+
| US1234  | 2019-03-19 12:30:45.000 | 2019-03-19  | No               |
| US1234  | 2019-03-19 15:30:45.000 | 2019-03-19  | Yes              |
| US1235  | 2019-03-20 09:30:45.000 | 2019-03-20  | No               |
| US1235  | 2019-03-23 12:40:45.000 | 2019-03-23  | Yes              |
| US1236  | 2019-03-20 12:30:45.000 | 2019-03-24  | Yes              |
| US1237  | 2019-03-25 12:30:45.000 | 2019-03-25  | No               |
+---------+-------------------------+-------------+------------------+
```

But thereafter you'll need to do something with the code that populates this table to maintain those values for future entries. That might require a two-step solution, but you'll have to decide after you review that code set. Maybe just run that `UPDATE` after the data load.